# Can a deftemplate construct have another template in a slot?

Tags: clips

I have a template defined as follows:

```
(deftemplate fact
    (slot name)
    (multislot field)
    (multislot value))
```

Can I have this above defined *fact* as a slot/multislot in another template?

For example:

```
(deftemplate collection1
    (slot fact1))

(deftemplate collection2
    (slot fact1)
    (slot fact2))
```

In the above desired template, each slot fact should be of defined template *fact*. I want to have such collection of
many number of slots. Or at least the desired outcome is to assert *collection* with fields similar to *fact* template.
So that I could have a logically link between name, fields and values.

```
(collection2
    (fact1 (name 'ID')
        (field 'Name' 'Company' 'Role')
        (value 'Bob' 'ABC' 'Admin'))
    (fact2 (name 'Event')
        (field 'Name' 'Place')
        (value 'Conference' 'USA')))
```

**Expected outcome** : CLIPS could assert the above recursive fact. Is this possible, or any alternative to the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, you can also restrict the slot type to specifically be a fact address.

```
(deftemplate fact
    (slot name)
    (multislot field)
    (multislot value))

(deftemplate collection
  (slot fact (type FACT-ADDRESS)))

(assert (collection (fact (assert (fact (name "ID")
                                        (field "Name" "Company" "Role")
                                        (value "Bob" "ABC" "Admin"))))))
```

The facts list:

```
(facts)          

f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (fact (name "ID") (field "Name" "Company" "Role") (value "Bob" "ABC" "Admin"))
f-2     (collection (fact <Fact-1>))
```